# mpdf is not downloading pdf document from live server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, mpdf

I tried to download a PDF file using mpdf in Codeigniter3.

This is my code which I have used for PDF generation

```
function download_PDF(){

  //load mPDF library
  $this->load->library('pdf'); 

   $pdfFilePath ="statement-".time().".pdf";    
   $html=$this->load->view("transactionStatement", true);       

   $pdf = $this->pdf->load();

   $stylesheet = '<style>'.file_get_contents('assets/css/style.css').'</style>';

   $pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
   $pdf->WriteHTML($html,2);

   $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
   exit;
}
```

This is my Library file

```
class Pdf {

    function Pdf()
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        log_message('Debug', 'mPDF class is loaded.');
    }
    function load($param=NULL)
    {
        include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';

        if ($params == NULL)
        {
            $param = '"en-GB-x","A4","","",10,10,10,10,6,3';                
        }
        return new mPDF();
    }
}
```

The above code working fine in local server but it is not working in live server.

in live server the url is like this **file:///C:/Users/Nibs2/Downloads/statement-1556794021.pdf** and it says '**Failed to load PDF document.**'

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does `$stylesheet` contain? Which part of your software outputs "Failed to load PDF document"?

Comment: when i click to open pdf with browser..then its not showing any html content in crome ...its just says falied to load doc

Comment: style sheet contains some css

Comment: And what **exactly** does that string contain in case of error? What **exactly** does the given PDF response contain? Don't guess, check and attach detailed information

Comment: I am not guessing

Comment: So, then what **exactly** does `$stylesheet` contain in case of error? And what's the raw content of that PDF file?

Comment: its contain---p{font-size:12px}